# JSP populate a dropdown list with a value taken from previous dropdown

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

In my Jsp page I have a first dropdown list, which it's simply loaded at the beginning, with data from db.

Onchange of the dropdown (#docentiDropList) I take the value chosen, and use it to filter the next dropdown, but I can't fill the jsp dropdown and I don't know why. 
Probably the problem is that, I should use the session instead of request...

Or in the jQuery/ajax success part, because, when selected the value from the first list, it's actually taken and it's passed to the servlet via the request, there the query correctly works and the results are set into the attribute request "materie" but then nothing appears into the dropdown list.

Here I set the request attribute with the result of query.

The java code

```java
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        //HttpSession s = request.getSession();
        try {
            List<String> materie = new ArrayList();
            String docenteDropList = request.getParameter("materie");
            if (docenteDropList != null) {
                Statement st = conn.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT giorno FROM prenotazioni WHERE studente='" + docenteDropList + "'");
                while (rs.next()) {
                    materie.add(rs.getString("giorno"));
                }
                request.setAttribute("materie", materie);
            }
            processRequest(request, response);
        } catch (...) {}
    }
```

my JSP file

```
 <select id="docentiDropList">
                <c:forEach items="${docenti}" var="docenti">
                    <option name="docenti" value="${docenti}">
                        ${docenti}
                    </option>
                </c:forEach>
            </select>


            <select id="materie" name="materie">
                <c:forEach items="${materie}" var="materie">
                    <option value="${materie}">
                        ${materie}
                    </option>
                </c:forEach>
            </select>
```

The jQuery code inside the JSP

```
      <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#docentiDropList").on("change", function () {
            var materie = $("#docentiDropList").val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "Controller",
                    method: "GET",
                    data: {materie: materie},
                    success: function (materie)
                    {
                        $("#materie").html(materie); 
                    }
                });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You need to use `out.println()` to show result back in your dropdown.. request attribute will not work in this case ,as you are using `ajax` or use you can use `json` and add value in `json-array` and print that in your success function.